# Create multiple sections on html <datalist>

Tags: html, html-datalist

I'm wondering if i can divide the `<datalist>` into sections like `<optgroup>` does. Many thanks!

Codes below:

```html
<label>Location:</label>
<select>
  <optgroup label="classroom">
    <option>1A</option>
    <option>1B</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br>

<label>Location</label>
<input type="text" name="location" class="form-control-lg" list="location">
<datalist id="location">
  <option value="Classroom">
  <option value="1A">
  <option value="1B">
</datalist>
```

Comment: This is not possible natively. There is a polyfill being worked on here: https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/932#issuecomment-315647887

Comment: @BenM Thanks, i'll surely try that out

Comment: There's an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310969/input-with-datalist-grouping